# ASP.Net - Create Entity Class From Query Fields - Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am very new to ASP.Net and MVC applications so pardon me if this question has been asked or is trivial.
I know how to create an entity model class from a database table, but I want to perform a series of Joins and create a Pivot table from an SQL query and then pass this to a view.
However, I do not know a quick way to create an entity class for this.
Currently, I am doing it the long way by manually defining a model class like so:

```
public class OAData
    {
        public int Zone { get; set; }
        public string Device { get; set; }
        public string Part { get; set; }
...

        //CONSTRUCTOR
        public OAData(int zone, string device, string part...){
            Zone = zone;
            Device = device;
            Part = part;
            ...
        }
    }
```

and then create a database connection in the controller, loop through all the records, creating *OAData* objects for each record, add it to a list and then pass that list to the View.
Is there an easier way to do this (there are many fields returned by the query)? Can I create a model from a complex SQL query rather than just off a database table?

Comment: Which approach are you following? Code first of DB first ? if you are not sure about these concept , i recommend these videos by Scott Allen :
http://pluralsight.com/training/Player?author=scott-allen&name=mvc4-building-m4-data-i&mode=live&clip=0&course=mvc4-building

Comment: Thanks. DbFirst is the appraoch I am using. The database is established and built by another application.

Comment: I would suggest using an ORM, Entity Framework works best with ASP.NET

Comment: That is exactly what I would like to do. However, I am struggling with figuring out how to create a model for combined tables. Let's suppose I have Table 1 which consists of ID and FirstName fields. Now I have Table 2 consisting of ID, LastName and T1Ref. I can create a model for Table 1 and a model for Table 2. How do I create a model for the joined table : SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = T1Ref